# Independence/ Asymptotic independence of asymptotic normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics, normal-distribution, independence

Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in I}$ be a sequence of independent random variables, where $X_{n}$ takes value $\{-c_n,c_n\}$, each with probability $1/2$, $c_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $I$ denotes the index set such that $\text{cardinality}(I) = d$. Suppose $I_{1}, I_{2}, \ldots, I_{K}$ are subsets of $I$ such that $I_{i} \cap I_{j} = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$, $\cup_{k \in \{1,\ldots, K\}} I_{k} = I$, and, for  $k \in \{1,\ldots,K\}$, $\text{cardinality}(I_{k}) = d/K$. Let $\{X_{n_{k}}\}_{n_{k} \in I_{k}}$, $k \in \{1,\ldots,K\}$, are $K$ sub-sequences of sequence $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in I}$. For $k \in \{1,\ldots,K\}$, we denote $\bar{X}_{k} := \sum_{n_{k} \in I_{k}} X_{n_{k}}$. If $K=o(d)$ and $d \rightarrow \infty$, then due to the Central Limit theorem for each $k  \in \{1,\ldots, K\}$, we have
\begin{align}
    \bar{X}_{{k}} = \sum_{n_{k} \in I_{k}} X_{n_{k}} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2), \quad \sigma > 0,
\end{align}
in distribution. Can we say something about the independence (or asymptotic independence) of  $\bar{X}_{{1}}, \bar{X}_{2}, \ldots, \bar{X}_{{K}}$ in general or under some condition?

Comment: Do you assume the $X_n$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, $X_n$ are independent.